# Django session cookie fails on IE if you have SSL/TLS enabled on a non-www and www domain name with different sessions

Tags: django, .htaccess, session, cookies

***My Website works perfectly fine on Chrome/Firefox/Opera***

***But on IE it does not always work.***

What is the case:

- I have a website that is only accessible via https
- You can go to https://example.com or https://www.example.com and see the same website
- However, depending on if you come with or without prefix, another session will be created in my Django application.
- This works fine in all browsers, except IE.
- Why? All browsers detect if they need to send the cookie without or with the prefix, except IE who just takes the first one that has ever been created.
- I have been struggling with all kinds of apache rewriterules etc, but they only handicap my REST API ("Method not allowed" for POST requests).
- As long as users only go to one of both prefixes there is no problem, but it happens that users always do things you don't expect.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Might sound like a stupid suggestion, but since your app works in Chrome, Firefox and Opera properly, then it means IE isn't doing something right. Does it work on Edge? If so, then gently tell users only these browsers are supported when they hit your site with IE. As much as I build cross-browser apps, IE enjoys a less than 1% of my priority.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but IE 11 (Edge) also has the same problem :(

Comment: Is there a reason why you are serving the site on two hosts, instead of just redirecting all traffic to one of them? Doing so would resolve your issue and also ensure that there is one canonical host for your site.

Comment: the http sites are both redirected to https://www.example.com, but I cannot redirect the https://example.com to https://www.example.com. I tried everything, but everytime something breaks (for example 'method not found' when POSTing data, and other unresolvable things)... please note I also have app.example.com for example.

Comment: I ended up redirecting all trafic to www. example.com. Users that still had the old cookies and used IE or Edge were asked to clear all browser cookies. It is working fine since then :)